# Flutter, Android, how to upgrade to Billing Library version 3?

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, google-play-services, flutter-dependencies

I`m using Flutter

And in this update, I`m going to upgrade to Billing Library version 3 as requested by Google.

but I do not know how to do this?

I never wrote the version in the first place.

I`m currently using "in_app_purchase" package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See its [changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase/changelog).
In version `0.5.0` they updated to Billing version 3. No need to do anything on your side, just to use latest version of this pub package.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade version from in_app_purchase: ^0.4.0, Does not support Billing version 3, And from here starts null safety concept, which depends on flutter 2, if you use Billing version 3 on flutter 1, you can use alternate package of in app purchase , flutter_inapp_purchase: ^4.0.2 (this is use Billing version 3).

thank you